# CSS - Dynamically set height and width of img to fit content

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to dynamically size an image to fit in a div container.

For instance, I want to have a parent container with a max height of 50% and a max width of 100%. I then want to fit an image inside of there. If the image is landscape and is within the max height of the parent container, it should stretch all the way across horizontally, but be as tall as it needs to be. If the image is portrait and is OVER the max height of the parent container, it should stop at max 50% and be as wide as it needs to be depending on the ratio of the photo.

Thank you.

I tried to add a parent div with height: 50% and width: 100%, then I added max-height: 100% and max-width: 100% to the child image. It works fine for photos taller than the 50%, however if the photo is shorter than 50%, that div still takes up 50% regardless and creates ugly whitespace underneath the photo.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provides code nor html, all I can say it's you can use `object-fit: contain;` css property on image's parent to contain image without lose aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You want to preserve the image's aspect ratio, and scale as possible, respecting the maximum of 50% height and 100% width. Is that correct?

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/600">
</div>

<style>
  html, body{
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 50%;
}

.container img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
</style>
```

You can explore testing with the values in [this Codepen live example](https://codepen.io/edinella/pen/poxJOYa?editors=1100).